# What is the best way to define custom methods on a DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to define custom methods on DataFrame. What is the better way to do it? The solution should be scalable, as I intend to define a  significant number of custom methods.

My current approach is to create a class (say `MyClass`) with `DataFrame` as parameter, define my custom method (say `customMethod`) in that and define an implicit method which converts `DataFrame` to `MyClass`.

```
implicit def dataFrametoMyClass(df: DataFrame): MyClass = new MyClass(df)
```

Thus I can call:

```
dataFrame.customMethod()
```

Is this the correct way to do it? Open for suggestions.

Answer (score 26):

Your way is the way to go (see [1]). Even though I solved it a little different, the approach stays similar:

### Possibility 1

#### Implicits

```
object ExtraDataFrameOperations {
  object implicits {
    implicit def dFWithExtraOperations(df: DataFrame) = DFWithExtraOperations(df)
  }
}

case class DFWithExtraOperations(df: DataFrame) {
  def customMethod(param: String) : DataFrame = {
    // do something fancy with the df
    // or delegate to some implementation
    //
    // here, just as an illustrating example: do a select
    df.select( df(param) )
  }
}
```

#### Usage

To use the new `customMethod` method on a `DataFrame`:

```
import ExtraDataFrameOperations.implicits._
val df = ...
val otherDF = df.customMethod("hello")
```

### Possibility 2

Instead of using an `implicit method` (see above), you can also use an `implicit class`:

#### Implicit class

```
object ExtraDataFrameOperations {
  implicit class DFWithExtraOperations(df : DataFrame) {
     def customMethod(param: String) : DataFrame = {
      // do something fancy with the df
      // or delegate to some implementation
      //
      // here, just as an illustrating example: do a select
      df.select( df(param) )
    }
  }
}
```

#### Usage

```
import ExtraDataFrameOperations._
val df = ...
val otherDF = df.customMethod("hello")
```

### Remark

In case you want to prevent the additional `import`, turn the `object` `ExtraDataFrameOperations` into an `package object` and store it in in a file called `package.scala` within your package.

### Official documentation / references

[1] The original blog "Pimp my library" by M. Odersky is available at http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766

Comment: thank you for very profound answer! Which possibility is easier to adapt to be able of doing "import spark.implicits._"? The former annoyingly needs SparkSession object and this is a headache!

Answer (score 12):

There is a slightly simpler approach: just [declare `MyClass` as `implicit`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html)

```
implicit class MyClass(df: DataFrame) { def myMethod = ... }
```

This automatically creates the implicit conversion method (also called `MyClass`). You can also make it a [value class](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html) by adding `extends AnyVal` which avoids some overhead by not actually creating a `MyClass` instance at runtime, but this is very unlikely to matter in practice.

Finally, putting `MyClass` into a [`package object`](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/packageobjects/packageobjects.html) will allow you to use the new methods anywhere in this package without requiring import of `MyClass`, which may be a benefit or a drawback for you.

Comment: thank you for very concise solution! Similarly to my question to Martin: is it possible to adapt this solution to be able of nicely doing "import spark.implicits._"? The former annoyingly needs SparkSession object and this is a headache!

Comment: How is it a headache? If the problem is that you have to pass the SparkSession alongside the DataFrame, you don't, it's available: you can write `import df.sparkSession.implicits._`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add an implicit conversion between DataFrame and your custom wrapper, but use an implicit clas - this should be the easiest to use and you will store your custom methods in one common place.

```
   implicit class WrappedDataFrame(val df: DataFrame) {
        def customMethod(String arg1, int arg2) {
           ...[do your stuff here]
        }
     ...[other methods you consider useful, getters, setters, whatever]...
      }
```

If the implicit wrapper is in DataFrame's scope, you can just use normal DataFrame as if it was your wrapper, ie.:

df.customMethod("test", 100)