# Dropping a nested column from Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I have a `DataFrame` with the schema

```
root
 |-- label: string (nullable = true)
 |-- features: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- feat1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- feat2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- feat3: string (nullable = true)
```

While, I am able to filter the data frame using

```
  val data = rawData
     .filter( !(rawData("features.feat1") <=> "100") )
```

I am unable to drop the columns using

```
  val data = rawData
       .drop("features.feat1")
```

Is it something that I am doing wrong here? I also tried (unsuccessfully) doing `drop(rawData("features.feat1"))`, though it does not make much sense to do so.

Thanks in advance,

Nikhil

Comment: What if you mapped it to a new dataframe instead? I don't think the DataFrame API allows you to drop a struct field within a struct column type.

Comment: Ohh. I will try that, but seems pretty inconvenient if I have to map just to resolve a nested column name this way :(.

Comment: You can always get all columns with the DataFrame's `.columns()` method, remove unwanted column from the sequence and do `select(myColumns:_*)`. Should be a bit shorter.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is just a programming exercise but you can try something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Column}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{functions => f}
import scala.util.Try

case class DFWithDropFrom(df: DataFrame) {
  def getSourceField(source: String): Try[StructField] = {
    Try(df.schema.fields.filter(_.name == source).head)
  }

  def getType(sourceField: StructField): Try[StructType] = {
    Try(sourceField.dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType])
  }

  def genOutputCol(names: Array[String], source: String): Column = {
    f.struct(names.map(x => f.col(source).getItem(x).alias(x)): _*)
  }

  def dropFrom(source: String, toDrop: Array[String]): DataFrame = {
    getSourceField(source)
      .flatMap(getType)
      .map(_.fieldNames.diff(toDrop))
      .map(genOutputCol(_, source))
      .map(df.withColumn(source, _))
      .getOrElse(df)
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
scala> case class features(feat1: String, feat2: String, feat3: String)
defined class features

scala> case class record(label: String, features: features)
defined class record

scala> val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(record("a_label",  features("f1", "f2", "f3")))).toDF
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [label: string, features: struct<feat1:string,feat2:string,feat3:string>]

scala> DFWithDropFrom(df).dropFrom("features", Array("feat1")).show
+-------+--------+
|  label|features|
+-------+--------+
|a_label| [f2,f3]|
+-------+--------+


scala> DFWithDropFrom(df).dropFrom("foobar", Array("feat1")).show
+-------+----------+
|  label|  features|
+-------+----------+
|a_label|[f1,f2,f3]|
+-------+----------+


scala> DFWithDropFrom(df).dropFrom("features", Array("foobar")).show
+-------+----------+
|  label|  features|
+-------+----------+
|a_label|[f1,f2,f3]|
+-------+----------+
```

Add an [implicit conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32638654/15600622) and you're good to go.

Comment: Although I have upvoated this answer because it works when all nested rows have uniform schema-- otherwise it does not work - it just returns the original DataFrame.

Comment: As it appears the problem was with getOrElse part of the statement, if there is any exception thrown it does not get printed and 'Else' part takes over and it returns original DataFrame. For example, in my case, case insensitivity was the issue - there were two columns with same name but in different cases.

Answer (score 26):

This version allows you to remove nested columns at any level:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, DataType}

/**
  * Various Spark utilities and extensions of DataFrame
  */
object DataFrameUtils {

  private def dropSubColumn(col: Column, colType: DataType, fullColName: String, dropColName: String): Option[Column] = {
    if (fullColName.equals(dropColName)) {
      None
    } else {
      colType match {
        case colType: StructType =>
          if (dropColName.startsWith(s"${fullColName}.")) {
            Some(struct(
              colType.fields
                .flatMap(f =>
                  dropSubColumn(col.getField(f.name), f.dataType, s"${fullColName}.${f.name}", dropColName) match {
                    case Some(x) => Some(x.alias(f.name))
                    case None => None
                  })
                : _*))
          } else {
            Some(col)
          }
        case other => Some(col)
      }
    }
  }

  protected def dropColumn(df: DataFrame, colName: String): DataFrame = {
    df.schema.fields
      .flatMap(f => {
        if (colName.startsWith(s"${f.name}.")) {
          dropSubColumn(col(f.name), f.dataType, f.name, colName) match {
            case Some(x) => Some((f.name, x))
            case None => None
          }
        } else {
          None
        }
      })
      .foldLeft(df.drop(colName)) {
        case (df, (colName, column)) => df.withColumn(colName, column)
      }
  }

  /**
    * Extended version of DataFrame that allows to operate on nested fields
    */
  implicit class ExtendedDataFrame(df: DataFrame) extends Serializable {
    /**
      * Drops nested field from DataFrame
      *
      * @param colName Dot-separated nested field name
      */
    def dropNestedColumn(colName: String): DataFrame = {
      DataFrameUtils.dropColumn(df, colName)
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
import DataFrameUtils._
df.dropNestedColumn("a.b.c.d")
```

Comment: Thanks much! Any chance you've updated this to drop a field from a struct in an array under an array?  Been hacking for over a day now, close but can't get it. i.e. parent:array<element:struct<child:array<element:struct<keep:int, drop:int>>>>

Comment: @alexP_Keaton Hey, did you get a solution for dropping a column inside an array?

Comment: I would like to add that this method does not preserve 'nullable' property of the modified parent struct.  In this example, `features` will become `struct (nullable = false)`

Comment: One way I found to fix this issue is to pass `f.nullable` to dropSubColumn and use this construct `when(col.isNotNull, newCol)` on the result of `struct(... :_*)`

Comment: You actually don't need the `df.drop(colName)` bit here.  It doesn't work anyway (or else we could simply drop nested columns using the API directly).  Also, the `withColumn` will replace an existing column name with a new definition if given.

Comment: Does anyone have a similar solution for adding an optional (nullable) column in a deeply nested struct field.

Answer (score 6):

Expanding on spektom answer. With support for array types:

```scala
object DataFrameUtils {

  private def dropSubColumn(col: Column, colType: DataType, fullColName: String, dropColName: String): Option[Column] = {
    if (fullColName.equals(dropColName)) {
      None
    } else if (dropColName.startsWith(s"$fullColName.")) {
      colType match {
        case colType: StructType =>
          Some(struct(
            colType.fields
              .flatMap(f =>
                dropSubColumn(col.getField(f.name), f.dataType, s"$fullColName.${f.name}", dropColName) match {
                  case Some(x) => Some(x.alias(f.name))
                  case None => None
                })
              : _*))
        case colType: ArrayType =>
          colType.elementType match {
            case innerType: StructType =>
              Some(struct(innerType.fields
                .flatMap(f =>
                  dropSubColumn(col.getField(f.name), f.dataType, s"$fullColName.${f.name}", dropColName) match {
                    case Some(x) => Some(x.alias(f.name))
                    case None => None
                  })
                : _*))
          }

        case other => Some(col)
      }
    } else {
      Some(col)
    }
  }

  protected def dropColumn(df: DataFrame, colName: String): DataFrame = {
    df.schema.fields
      .flatMap(f => {
        if (colName.startsWith(s"${f.name}.")) {
          dropSubColumn(col(f.name), f.dataType, f.name, colName) match {
            case Some(x) => Some((f.name, x))
            case None => None
          }
        } else {
          None
        }
      })
      .foldLeft(df.drop(colName)) {
        case (df, (colName, column)) => df.withColumn(colName, column)
      }
  }

  /**
    * Extended version of DataFrame that allows to operate on nested fields
    */
  implicit class ExtendedDataFrame(df: DataFrame) extends Serializable {
    /**
      * Drops nested field from DataFrame
      *
      * @param colName Dot-separated nested field name
      */
    def dropNestedColumn(colName: String): DataFrame = {
      DataFrameUtils.dropColumn(df, colName)
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: The call to `struct` within `case colType: ArrayType` needs to be wrapped in `array`, or else you "lose" the array wrapping a parent of the column removed.  In addition, the remaining items in the lowest struct (i.e. the one with a member that gets removed) get converted to `array` for some reason, which I'm still debugging.

Comment: @JeffEvans did you find the reason why that happens (field getting converted to array) ? I debugged all day long and I can't understand what Spark's doing there. Might be a bug?

Comment: Not sure.  It's possible the code we're working off of isn't correct, but I can't understand the innards of the Spark library code well enough yet to say for certain.

Comment: as @JeffEvans mentioned there is a bug here that converts the remaining items into array. to avoid it you should this: `case Some(x) => Some(x.getItem(0).alias(f.name))` instead of `case Some(x) => Some(x.alias(f.name))` in ArrayType case

Comment: Doing `.getItem(0)` before the `alias` (inside the `ArrayType` -> `StructType` case) does indeed "work".  However, this really shouldn't be needed.  I believe there is a bug in Spark itself, so I have opened a Jira for that: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-31779

Comment: It seems that the Spark maintainers do not agree this is a bug. Nonetheless, given their comments on the Jira I opened, I can confirm a workaround. Will paste as a separate answer. – Jeff Evans 6 hours ago   Delete

Answer (score 6):

For Spark 3.1+, you can use method [`dropFields`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#dropFields(fieldNames:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) on struct type columns:

> An expression that drops fields in StructType by name. This is a no-op
> if schema doesn't contain field name(s).

```scala
val df = sql("SELECT named_struct('feat1', 1, 'feat2', 2, 'feat3', 3) features")

val df1 = df.withColumn("features", $"features".dropFields("feat1"))
```

Comment: Not working when there is a need to drop the field in struct wrapped by array

Answer (score 5):

I will expand upon mmendez.semantic's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46084983/375670), and accounting for the issues described in the sub-thread.

```
  def dropSubColumn(col: Column, colType: DataType, fullColName: String, dropColName: String): Option[Column] = {
    if (fullColName.equals(dropColName)) {
      None
    } else if (dropColName.startsWith(s"$fullColName.")) {
      colType match {
        case colType: StructType =>
          Some(struct(
            colType.fields
                .flatMap(f =>
                  dropSubColumn(col.getField(f.name), f.dataType, s"$fullColName.${f.name}", dropColName) match {
                    case Some(x) => Some(x.alias(f.name))
                    case None => None
                  })
                : _*))
        case colType: ArrayType =>
          colType.elementType match {
            case innerType: StructType =>
              // we are potentially dropping a column from within a struct, that is itself inside an array
              // Spark has some very strange behavior in this case, which they insist is not a bug
              // see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-31779 and associated comments
              // and also the thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39943812/375670
              // this is a workaround for that behavior

              // first, get all struct fields
              val innerFields = innerType.fields
              // next, create a new type for all the struct fields EXCEPT the column that is to be dropped
              // we will need this later
              val preserveNamesStruct = ArrayType(StructType(
                innerFields.filterNot(f => s"$fullColName.${f.name}".equals(dropColName))
              ))
              // next, apply dropSubColumn recursively to build up the new values after dropping the column
              val filteredInnerFields = innerFields.flatMap(f =>
                dropSubColumn(col.getField(f.name), f.dataType, s"$fullColName.${f.name}", dropColName) match {
                    case Some(x) => Some(x.alias(f.name))
                    case None => None
                }
              )
              // finally, use arrays_zip to unwrap the arrays that were introduced by building up the new. filtered
              // struct in this way (see comments in SPARK-31779), and then cast to the StructType we created earlier
              // to get the original names back
              Some(arrays_zip(filteredInnerFields:_*).cast(preserveNamesStruct))
          }

        case _ => Some(col)
      }
    } else {
      Some(col)
    }
  }

  def dropColumn(df: DataFrame, colName: String): DataFrame = {
    df.schema.fields.flatMap(f => {
      if (colName.startsWith(s"${f.name}.")) {
        dropSubColumn(col(f.name), f.dataType, f.name, colName) match {
          case Some(x) => Some((f.name, x))
          case None => None
        }
      } else {
        None
      }
    }).foldLeft(df.drop(colName)) {
      case (df, (colName, column)) => df.withColumn(colName, column)
    }
  }
```

Usage in `spark-shell`:

```
// if defining the functions above in your spark-shell session, you first need imports
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

// now you can paste the function definitions

// create a deeply nested and complex JSON structure    
val jsonData = """{
      "foo": "bar",
      "top": {
        "child1": 5,
        "child2": [
          {
            "child2First": "one",
            "child2Second": 2,
            "child2Third": -19.51
          }
        ],
        "child3": ["foo", "bar", "baz"],
        "child4": [
          {
            "child2First": "two",
            "child2Second": 3,
            "child2Third": 16.78
          }
        ]
      }
    }"""

// read it into a DataFrame
val df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json(Seq(jsonData).toDS())

// remove a sub-column
val modifiedDf = dropColumn(df, "top.child2.child2First")

modifiedDf.printSchema
root
 |-- foo: string (nullable = true)
 |-- top: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- child1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- child2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- child2Second: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- child2Third: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- child3: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- child4: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- child2First: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- child2Second: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- child2Third: double (nullable = true)


modifiedDf.show(truncate=false)
+---+------------------------------------------------------+
|foo|top                                                   |
+---+------------------------------------------------------+
|bar|[5, [[2, -19.51]], [foo, bar, baz], [[two, 3, 16.78]]]|
+---+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I see we are using  "arrays_zip" in the def call "dropSubColumn"  but as of spark 2.3 this will not work , is there an alternative to do this. I tried to create an UDF as below but no luck in using the same.  
    val zipped = udf((s: Seq[String],t: Seq[String]) => s zip t)

Comment: As I recall, this was working in 2.4. But I no longer have access to the underlying project code so I'm not sure. Should be easy to use spark-shell to test.

Answer (score 4):

Another (PySpark) way would be to drop the `features.feat1` column by creating `features` again:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, arrays_zip

display(df
        .withColumn("features", arrays_zip("features.feat2", "features.feat3"))
        .withColumn("features", col("features").cast(schema))
)
```

Where `schema` is the new schema (excluding `features.feat1`).

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType

schema = StructType(
    [
      StructField('feat2', StringType(), True), 
      StructField('feat3', StringType(), True), 
    ]
  )
```

Comment: Award winning answer.  Was not aware of arrays_zip().

Answer (score 2):

Following spektom's code snippet for scala, I've created a similar code in Java. 
Since java 8 doesn't have foldLeft, I used forEachOrdered. This code is suitable for spark 2.x (I'm using 2.1)
Also I noted that dropping a column and adding it using withColumn with the same name doesn't work, so I'm just replacing the column, and it seem to work.

Code is not fully tested, hope it works :-)

```
public class DataFrameUtils {

public static Dataset<Row> dropNestedColumn(Dataset<Row> dataFrame, String columnName) {
    final DataFrameFolder dataFrameFolder = new DataFrameFolder(dataFrame);
    Arrays.stream(dataFrame.schema().fields())
        .flatMap( f -> {
           if (columnName.startsWith(f.name() + ".")) {
               final Optional<Column> column = dropSubColumn(col(f.name()), f.dataType(), f.name(), columnName);
               if (column.isPresent()) {
                   return Stream.of(new Tuple2<>(f.name(), column));
               } else {
                   return Stream.empty();
               }
           } else {
               return Stream.empty();
           }
        }).forEachOrdered(colTuple -> dataFrameFolder.accept(colTuple));

    return dataFrameFolder.getDF();
}

private static Optional<Column> dropSubColumn(Column col, DataType colType, String fullColumnName, String dropColumnName) {
    Optional<Column> column = Optional.empty();
    if (!fullColumnName.equals(dropColumnName)) {
        if (colType instanceof StructType) {
            if (dropColumnName.startsWith(fullColumnName + ".")) {
                column = Optional.of(struct(getColumns(col, (StructType)colType, fullColumnName, dropColumnName)));
            }
        } else {
            column = Optional.of(col);
        }
    }

    return column;
}

private static Column[] getColumns(Column col, StructType colType, String fullColumnName, String dropColumnName) {
    return Arrays.stream(colType.fields())
        .flatMap(f -> {
                    final Optional<Column> column = dropSubColumn(col.getField(f.name()), f.dataType(),
                            fullColumnName + "." + f.name(), dropColumnName);
                    if (column.isPresent()) {
                        return Stream.of(column.get().alias(f.name()));
                    } else {
                        return Stream.empty();
                    }
                }
        ).toArray(Column[]::new);

}

private static class DataFrameFolder implements Consumer<Tuple2<String, Optional<Column>>> {
    private Dataset<Row> df;

    public DataFrameFolder(Dataset<Row> df) {
        this.df = df;
    }

    public Dataset<Row> getDF() {
        return df;
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(Tuple2<String, Optional<Column>> colTuple) {
        if (!colTuple._2().isPresent()) {
            df = df.drop(colTuple._1());
        } else {
            df = df.withColumn(colTuple._1(), colTuple._2().get());
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
private class Pojo {
    private String str;
    private Integer number;
    private List<String> strList;
    private Pojo2 pojo2;

    public String getStr() {
        return str;
    }

    public Integer getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public List<String> getStrList() {
        return strList;
    }

    public Pojo2 getPojo2() {
        return pojo2;
    }

}

private class Pojo2 {
    private String str;
    private Integer number;
    private List<String> strList;

    public String getStr() {
        return str;
    }

    public Integer getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public List<String> getStrList() {
        return strList;
    }

}

SQLContext context = new SQLContext(new SparkContext("local[1]", "test"));
Dataset<Row> df = context.createDataFrame(Collections.emptyList(), Pojo.class);
Dataset<Row> dfRes = DataFrameUtils.dropNestedColumn(df, "pojo2.str");
```

Original struct:

```
root
 |-- number: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- pojo2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- number: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- str: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- strList: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- str: string (nullable = true)
 |-- strList: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

After drop:

```
root
 |-- number: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- pojo2: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- number: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- strList: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- str: string (nullable = true)
 |-- strList: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Comment: add a simple example of how to call it and i will upvote you

Comment: Added usage example per @xXxpRoGrAmmErxXx request

Answer (score 2):

PySpark implementation

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as sf

def _drop_nested_field(
    schema: StructType,
    field_to_drop: str,
    parents: List[str] = None,
) -> Column:
    parents = list() if parents is None else parents
    src_col = lambda field_names: sf.col('.'.join(f'`{c}`' for c in field_names))

    if '.' in field_to_drop:
        root, subfield = field_to_drop.split('.', maxsplit=1)
        field_to_drop_from = next(f for f in schema.fields if f.name == root)

        return sf.struct(
            *[src_col(parents + [f.name]) for f in schema.fields if f.name != root],
            _drop_nested_field(
                schema=field_to_drop_from.dataType,
                field_to_drop=subfield,
                parents=parents + [root]
            ).alias(root)
        )

    else:
        # select all columns except the one to drop
        return sf.struct(
            *[src_col(parents + [f.name])for f in schema.fields if f.name != field_to_drop],
        )


def drop_nested_field(
    df: DataFrame,
    field_to_drop: str,
) -> DataFrame:
    if '.' in field_to_drop:
        root, subfield = field_to_drop.split('.', maxsplit=1)
        field_to_drop_from = next(f for f in df.schema.fields if f.name == root)

        return df.withColumn(root, _drop_nested_field(
            schema=field_to_drop_from.dataType,
            field_to_drop=subfield,
            parents=[root]
        ))
    else:
        return df.drop(field_to_drop)


df = drop_nested_field(df, 'a.b.c.d')
```

Comment: what is sf in _drop_nested_field?

Comment: @prakharjain `import pyspark.sql.functions as sf` 
I've updated the example.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the java version Solution for this.

Utility Class(Pass your dataset and the nested column which has to be dropped to dropNestedColumn function).

(There are few bugs in Lior Chaga's answer, I have corrected them while I tried to use his answer).

```
public class NestedColumnActions {
/*
dataset : dataset in which we want to drop columns
columnName : nested column that needs to be deleted
*/
public static Dataset<?> dropNestedColumn(Dataset<?> dataset, String columnName) {

    //Special case of top level column deletion
    if(!columnName.contains("."))
        return dataset.drop(columnName);

    final DataSetModifier dataFrameFolder = new DataSetModifier(dataset);
    Arrays.stream(dataset.schema().fields())
            .flatMap(f -> {
                //If the column name to be deleted starts with current top level column
                if (columnName.startsWith(f.name() + DOT)) {
                    //Get new column structure under f , expected after deleting the required column
                    final Optional<Column> column = dropSubColumn(functions.col(f.name()), f.dataType(), f.name(), columnName);
                    if (column.isPresent()) {
                        return Stream.of(new Tuple2<>(f.name(), column));
                    } else {
                        return Stream.empty();
                    }
                } else {
                    return Stream.empty();
                }
            })
            //Call accept function with Tuples of (top level column name, new column structure under it)
            .forEach(colTuple -> dataFrameFolder.accept(colTuple));

    return dataFrameFolder.getDataset();
}

private static Optional<Column> dropSubColumn(Column col, DataType colType, String fullColumnName, String dropColumnName) {
    Optional<Column> column = Optional.empty();
    if (!fullColumnName.equals(dropColumnName)) {
        if (colType instanceof StructType) {
            if (dropColumnName.startsWith(fullColumnName + DOT)) {
                column = Optional.of(functions.struct(getColumns(col, (StructType) colType, fullColumnName, dropColumnName)));
            }
            else {
                column = Optional.of(col);
            }
        } else {
            column = Optional.of(col);
        }
    }

    return column;
}

private static Column[] getColumns(Column col, StructType colType, String fullColumnName, String dropColumnName) {
    return Arrays.stream(colType.fields())
            .flatMap(f -> {
                        final Optional<Column> column = dropSubColumn(col.getField(f.name()), f.dataType(),
                                fullColumnName + "." + f.name(), dropColumnName);
                        if (column.isPresent()) {
                            return Stream.of(column.get().alias(f.name()));
                        } else {
                            return Stream.empty();
                        }
                    }
            ).toArray(Column[]::new);

}

private static class DataSetModifier implements Consumer<Tuple2<String, Optional<Column>>> {
    private Dataset<?> df;

    public DataSetModifier(Dataset<?> df) {
        this.df = df;
    }

    public Dataset<?> getDataset() {
        return df;
    }

    /*
    colTuple[0]:top level column name
    colTuple[1]:new column structure under it
   */
    @Override
    public void accept(Tuple2<String, Optional<Column>> colTuple) {
        if (!colTuple._2().isPresent()) {
            df = df.drop(colTuple._1());
        } else {
            df = df.withColumn(colTuple._1(), colTuple._2().get());
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The [Make Structs Easy](https://github.com/fqaiser94/mse)* library makes it easy to perform operations like adding, dropping, and renaming fields inside nested data structures. The library is available in both Scala and Python.

Assuming you have the following data:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

case class Features(feat1: String, feat2: String, feat3: String)
case class Record(features: Features, arrayOfFeatures: Seq[Features])

val df = Seq(
   Record(Features("hello", "world", "!"), Seq(Features("red", "orange", "yellow"), Features("green", "blue", "indigo")))
).toDF

df.printSchema

// root
//  |-- features: struct (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- feat1: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- feat2: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- feat3: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- arrayOfFeatures: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
//  |    |    |-- feat1: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- feat2: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- feat3: string (nullable = true)

df.show(false)

// +-----------------+----------------------------------------------+
// |features         |arrayOfFeatures                               |
// +-----------------+----------------------------------------------+
// |[hello, world, !]|[[red, orange, yellow], [green, blue, indigo]]|
// +-----------------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Then dropping `feat2` from `features` is as simple as:

```
import com.github.fqaiser94.mse.methods._

// drop feat2 from features
df.withColumn("features", $"features".dropFields("feat2")).show(false)

// +----------+----------------------------------------------+
// |features  |arrayOfFeatures                               |
// +----------+----------------------------------------------+
// |[hello, !]|[[red, orange, yellow], [green, blue, indigo]]|
// +----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

I noticed there were a lot of follow-up comments on other solutions asking if there's a way to drop a Column nested inside a struct nested inside of an array. This can be done by combining the functions provided by the [Make Structs Easy](https://github.com/fqaiser94/mse) library with the functions provided by [spark-hofs](https://github.com/AbsaOSS/spark-hofs/) library, as follows:

```
import za.co.absa.spark.hofs._

// drop feat2 in each element of arrayOfFeatures
df.withColumn("arrayOfFeatures", transform($"arrayOfFeatures", features => features.dropFields("feat2"))).show(false)

// +-----------------+--------------------------------+
// |features         |arrayOfFeatures                 |
// +-----------------+--------------------------------+
// |[hello, world, !]|[[red, yellow], [green, indigo]]|
// +-----------------+--------------------------------+
```

*Full disclosure: I am the author of the [Make Structs Easy](https://github.com/fqaiser94/mse) library that is referenced in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

With Spark 3.1+, short and effective:

```scala
object DatasetOps {
  implicit class DatasetOps[T](val dataset: Dataset[T]) {
    def dropFields(fieldNames: String*): DataFrame =
      fieldNames.foldLeft(dataset.toDF()) { (dataset, fieldName) =>
        val subFieldRegex = "(\\w+)\\.(.+)".r
        fieldName match {
          case subFieldRegex(columnName, subFieldPath) =>
            dataset.withColumn(columnName, col(columnName).dropFields(subFieldPath))
          case _ => dataset.drop(fieldName)
        }
      }
  }
}
```

This also preserves the required or not boolean in the schema.

Usage:

```scala
dataset.dropFields("some_column", "some_struct.some_sub_field.some_field")
```