# How to efficiently process records in rdd and maintain the structure of a record

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, apache-spark-sql

I have been working with `Google Analytics` data I have got in s3. I am loading the file as follows -

```
df = sc.textFile('s3n://BUCKET_NAME/2017/1/2/')
```

After this, I get an `RDD`. But if we want to see the schema I have loaded the data into `spark SQL` and the data schema is like this -

```
root
 |-- channelGrouping: string (nullable = true)
 |-- customDimensions: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- index: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- device: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- browser: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- browserSize: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- browserVersion: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- deviceCategory: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- flashVersion: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- isMobile: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |-- javaEnabled: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |-- language: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- mobileDeviceBranding: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- mobileDeviceInfo: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- mobileDeviceMarketingName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- mobileDeviceModel: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- mobileInputSelector: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- operatingSystem: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- operatingSystemVersion: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- screenColors: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- screenResolution: string (nullable = true)
 |-- fullVisitorId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- geoNetwork: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- cityId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- continent: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- country: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- latitude: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- longitude: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- metro: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- networkDomain: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- networkLocation: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- region: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- subContinent: string (nullable = true)
```

what I tried -

```
def remove_null_device(val):
    _ori = json.loads(val)
#     _ori = val
    _dic_val = _ori['device']
    for key, _value in _dic_val.items():
        if _value == "null":
            _dic_val[key] = "Hello There I am Testing this"
    _ori["device"] = _dic_val
    return _ori
device_data = df_rdd.map(remove_null_device)
```

Problem Statement - I want to iterate over every record as this is the nested structure I am thinking to pass one main key at a time like we have device, geoNetwork and check if the values are empty or not or null.

But this seems to change the structure of the whole record and the items are not getting updated don't know why. Please suggest any better approach for same.
Thanks!

Ok I want to check for all the fields in device if they are empty or null or (not set) and then updated those values and return the row I have updated and schema should remain intact.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to filter out a null value from spark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39727742/how-to-filter-out-a-null-value-from-spark-dataframe)

Comment: But I want to update the values in the nested structure right not the flat schema

Comment: Then take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41731000/adding-a-nested-column-to-spark-dataframe.. In spark, adding a column will overwrite existing one.

Comment: No but with the nested schema it will create the new column  right? and will the schema be intact?

Comment: can you help in pyspark?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not fluent enough in python to help out.  The thing is, `withColumn` works only for top level columns.  According to your schema, you could do `df.withColumn("channelGrouping", when(df("channelGrouping").isNull, lit("Some other value")))` and that would leave the schema intact.. For nested columns, see other post I linked