# Dropping nested column of Dataframe with PySpark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, struct, schema

I'm trying to drop some nested columns from structs in a Spark dataframe using PySpark.

I found this for Scala that seems to be doing exactly what I want to, but I'm not familiar with Scala and don't know how to write it in Python.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39943812/5706548

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A method that I found using pyspark is by first converting the nested column into json and then parse the converted json with a new nested schema with the unwanted columns filtered out.

Suppose I have the following schema and I want to drop `d`, `e` and `j` (`a.b.d`, `a.e`, `a.h.j`) from the dataframe:

```
root
 |-- a: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- b: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- c: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- d: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- e: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- f: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- g: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- h: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- i: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- j: string (nullable = true)
 |-- k: string (nullable = true)
```

I used the following approach:

1. Create new schema for `a` by excluding `d`, `e` and `j`. A quick way to do this is by manually select the fields that you want from `df.select("a").schema` and create a new schema from the selected fields using `StructType`. Or, you can do this programmatically by traversing the schema tree and exclude the unwanted fields, something like:

   ```
   def exclude_nested_field(schema, unwanted_fields, parent=""):
       new_schema = []

       for field in schema:
           full_field_name = field.name
           if parent:
               full_field_name = parent + "." + full_field_name

           if full_field_name not in unwanted_fields:
               if isinstance(field.dataType, StructType):
                   inner_schema = exclude_nested_field(field.dataType, unwanted_fields, full_field_name)
                   new_schema.append(StructField(field.name, inner_schema))
               elif isinstance(field.dataType, ArrayType):
                   new_schema.append(StructField(field.name, ArrayType(field.dataType.elementType)))
               else:
                   new_schema.append(StructField(field.name, field.dataType))

       return StructType(new_schema)

   new_schema = exclude_nested_field(df.schema["a"].dataType, ["b.d", "e", "h.j"])
   ```
2. Convert `a` column to json: `.withColumn("json", F.to_json("a")).drop("a")`
3. Parse the json-converted `a` column from step 2 with the new schema found in step 1: `.withColumn("a", F.from_json("json", new_schema)).drop("json")`

Comment: I'm trying to use this function but my structure has an array<struct<...>> and I'm getting "TypeError: 'ArrayType' object is not iterable" . Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: We now have something in Spark 3.1.1 to handle better the nested fields and be able to edit or drop them without touching the other ones https://germanschiavon.medium.com/spark-3-nested-fields-not-so-nested-anymore-9b8d34b00b95

Answer (score 6):

We can now do it natively with Spark version >= 3.1

https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.dropFields.html

Comment: Not working:
 File "C:\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py", line 1643, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dropFields'

Comment: it’s Column.dropFields, not DataFrame.dropFields @deathrace

Answer (score 5):

Example for pyspark:

```
def drop_col(df, struct_nm, delete_struct_child_col_nm):
    fields_to_keep = filter(lambda x:  x != delete_struct_child_col_nm, df.select("{}.*".format(struct_nm)).columns)
    fields_to_keep = list(map(lambda x:  "{}.{}".format(struct_nm, x), fields_to_keep))
    return df.withColumn(struct_nm, struct(fields_to_keep))
```

Comment: Could you please explain the parameters?

Comment: This seems to work for me.
df = dataframe
col_nm = parent column name
delete_col_nm = target sub-column to delete

Answer (score 2):

Having the below dataframe, the aim is to drop `d`, `e` and `j`.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([], "a struct<b:struct<c:bigint,d:string>,e:struct<f:bigint,g:string>,h:array<struct<i:string,j:string>>>, k string")
df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- a: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- b: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- c: long (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- d: string (nullable = true)      # <<--- to be dropped
#  |    |-- e: struct (nullable = true)           # <<--- to be dropped
#  |    |    |-- f: long (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- g: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- h: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |    |-- i: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |    |-- j: string (nullable = true)  # <<--- to be dropped
#  |-- k: string (nullable = true)
```

`e` is the easiest:

```py
df = df.withColumn("a", F.col("a").dropFields("e"))

df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- a: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- b: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- c: long (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- d: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- h: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |    |-- i: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |    |-- j: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- k: string (nullable = true)
```

In order to drop `d`, we must go inside `b`:

```py
df = df.withColumn("a", F.col("a").withField("b", F.col("a.b").dropFields("d")))

df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- a: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- b: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- c: long (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- h: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |    |-- i: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |    |-- j: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- k: string (nullable = true)
```

`j` is inside array, so [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.transform.html#pyspark.sql.functions.transform) must also be used. It "loops" through every array's elements (in this case, the element is a struct) and transforms it (removes a field).

```py
df = df.withColumn("a", F.col("a").withField(
    "h",
    F.transform(
        F.col("a.h"),
        lambda x: x.dropFields("j")
    )
))

df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- a: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- b: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- c: long (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- h: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |    |-- i: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- k: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Althoug I've no solution for PySpark, maybe it's easier to translate this into python. Consider a dataframe `df` with schema:

```
root
 |-- employee: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- age: integer (nullable = false)
```

Then if you want e.g. to drop `name`,
you can do:

```
val fieldsToKeep = df.select($"employee.*").columns
.filter(_!="name") // the nested column you want to drop
.map(n => "employee."+n)

// overwite column with subset of fields
df
.withColumn("employee",struct(fieldsToKeep.head,fieldsToKeep.tail:_*))
```

Answer (score 0):

Pyspark version of Raphaels Scala answer.

This runs at a certain depth, discards everything above that depth and filters on the row below it.

```
def remove_columns(df,root):
  from pyspark.sql.functions import col
  cols = df.select(root).columns
  fields_filter = filter(lambda x: x[0]!= "$", cols) # use your own lambda here. 
  fieldsToKeep = list(map(lambda x: root[:-1] + x, fields_filter)) 
  return df.select(fieldsToKeep)

df = remove_columns(raw_df, root="level1.level2.*")
```