# Remove Array Column from Array pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Consider I have the following data structure in a pyspark dataframe:

```
arr1:array
   element:struct
     string1:string
     arr2:array
         element:string
     string2: string
```

How can I remove the `arr2` from my dataframe?

Comment: use `to_json` + `from_json`, see one similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58243292

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `drop` function only. The way to select the nested columns is with `.`

Like `window.start` and `window.end`. You can access your `arr2` as `arr1.element.arr2`.

```
df.drop(df.element.arr2)
```