# convert json string to integer with pyspark

Tags: json, string, pyspark, type-conversion, integer

I want to convert a string object from json file into integer using pyspark.

```
df1.select(df1["`result.price`"]).dtypes

Out[15]: [('result.price', 'string')]
 df1=df1.withColumn(df1.select(df1["`result.price`"]),F.col(df1.select(df1["`result.price`"])).cast(T.IntegerType()))

'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

Comment: any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to modify inline:**

Since you are trying to modify the data type of nested struct field, I think you need to apply the new `StructType`.

Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63270808/2956135

**If you are okay with extracting to a different column:**

```py
df1 = df1.withColumn('price', F.col('result.price').cast(T.IntegerType()))
```

##### TL;DR

Why your line gives an error?

There is a few mistakes in this syntax.

```py
df1 = df1.withColumn(df1.select(df1["`result.price`"]),F.col(df1.select(df1["`result.price`"])).cast(T.IntegerType()))
```

First, 1st argument of `withColumn` has to be string of a column name that you want to save as.

Second, `F.col`'s argument has to be string of a column name or reference to the column.

So, this syntax should not throw an error, however, the casted value is saved to the new column.

```py
df1 = df1.withColumn('result.price', F.col('result.price').cast(T.IntegerType()))
```