# How to drop a nested array inside another array from a DataFrame, read in from JSON?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, nested

I am new to Scala and Spark. I have a question on dropping a nested array from my DataFrame.

This is my DataFrame schema:

```
  root
 |-- dedupeMode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- modules: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- content: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- weight: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- randomize: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- vars: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- test_group: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- vbs: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to get rid of the **content array** inside **modules array** .
Actually I want an empty content array to replace it. So when I write the JSON, I have it like *content[ ]*

I have tried like:

```
dataFrame.drop("modules.content")
```

and also went through the solutions at [Dropping a nested column from Spark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32727279/dropping-a-nested-column-from-spark-dataframe)

but did not solve my problem. I have also tried other variations without success. What would you recommend?

Comment: I have seen that question already. Sorry, but I think there should be a better solution for this problem. that question is 2y 1m old.

Comment: Could you clarify specifically which answers you have already tried and how it failed for you?  Otherwise it's hard to know what exact problem you're having.

Comment: Did you get the answer for this?