# Java - Spark drop column out of nested schema

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe in JAVA with nested column

below is the `.prinschema()` result

```
root
 |-- BeginDateTime: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _XmlNodeValue: string (nullable = true)
 |-- BusinessDayDate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- BusinessUnit: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- UnitID: struct (nullable = true)
```

I can use `dataframe.drop("BeginDateTime")` to drop the BeginDateTime column (as well as all other column right under the root node).

But if I do `dataframe.drop("BusinessUnit.UnitID")`, it will not drop it.

I tried this with other columns and they all behave the same: `can't drop a nested column.`

There are lots of answer for this question but they are all in scala/python. I have to work in a Java environment.

There is one thread ([Dropping a nested column from Spark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32727279/dropping-a-nested-column-from-spark-dataframe)), the last answer is in Java. But I can't use his code since line 8 and line 27 error out,

The errors are no method col, no method struct.

Can someone provide me with a working solution in JAVA?

Thanks

Comment: you can import col and struct methods with:
```import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col```,
```import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.struct```

Comment: @vinsce The col did work. the error I get now is in the struct. Intellij gives me two option:  1, Make getCOlumn retrun 'scala.collection.Seq<org.apache.spark.sql.column>'  Option 2: create method 'struct' in xxxx

Comment: struct(scala.collection.Seq,org.apache.spark.sql.Column>) in functions cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.COlumn[])