# How to drop nested column or filter nested column in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
root
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- h: string (nullable = true)
 |-- inc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- op: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ts: string (nullable = true)
 |-- webhooks: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- index: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- failed_at: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- status: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- updated_at: string (nullable = true)
```

How to remove the column  from (webhooks) by taking the input from list
eg filterList: List[String]= List("index","status"). Is there any way to do by iterating row like the intermediate schema will change not the final schema

```
root
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- h: string (nullable = true)
 |-- inc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- op: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ts: string (nullable = true)
 |-- webhooks: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- index: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- status: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check below code.

```
scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- h: string (nullable = true)
 |-- inc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- op: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ts: string (nullable = true)
 |-- webhooks: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- index: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- failed_at: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- status: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- updated_at: string (nullable = true)
```

```
scala> val actualColumns = df.select(s"webhooks.*").columns
```

```
scala> val removeColumns = Seq("index","status")
```

```
scala> val webhooks = struct(actualColumns.filter(c => !removeColumns.contains(c)).map(c => col(s"webhooks.${c}")):_*).as("webhooks")
```

**Output**

```
scala> df.withColumn("webhooks",webhooks).printSchema
root
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- h: string (nullable = true)
 |-- inc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- op: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ts: string (nullable = true)
 |-- webhooks: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- failed_at: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- updated_at: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Just  wanted to perform the operation on rows. Can We do ?

Answer (score 0):

Can also look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39943812/2204206

Can be more convenient when removing deeply nested columns