# Change nullable property of column in spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm manually creating a dataframe for some testing.  The code to create it is:

```
case class input(id:Long, var1:Int, var2:Int, var3:Double)
val inputDF = sqlCtx
  .createDataFrame(List(input(1110,0,1001,-10.00),
    input(1111,1,1001,10.00),
    input(1111,0,1002,10.00)))
```

So the schema looks like this:

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- var1: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- var2: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- var3: double (nullable = false)
```

I want to make 'nullable = true' for each one of these variable.  How do I declare that from the start or switch it in a new dataframe after it's been created?

Comment: `input` should instead be `Input` - case class names should be capitalized (title case)

Comment: https://medium.com/@pradipsudo/explore-nullable-property-of-columns-in-a-spark-data-frame-1d1b7b042adb

Comment: StructType.toNullable, ArrayType.toNullable and MapType.toNullable will be added from Spark 4.0.0, see also https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-45661

Answer (score 53, accepted):

#### Answer

With the imports

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructField, StructType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SQLContext}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
```

you can use

```
/**
 * Set nullable property of column.
 * @param df source DataFrame
 * @param cn is the column name to change
 * @param nullable is the flag to set, such that the column is  either nullable or not
 */
def setNullableStateOfColumn( df: DataFrame, cn: String, nullable: Boolean) : DataFrame = {

  // get schema
  val schema = df.schema
  // modify [[StructField] with name `cn`
  val newSchema = StructType(schema.map {
    case StructField( c, t, _, m) if c.equals(cn) => StructField( c, t, nullable = nullable, m)
    case y: StructField => y
  })
  // apply new schema
  df.sqlContext.createDataFrame( df.rdd, newSchema )
}
```

directly.

Also you can make the method available via the "pimp my library" library pattern ( see my SO post [What is the best way to define custom methods on a DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32585670/what-is-the-best-way-to-define-custom-methods-on-a-dataframe) ), such that you can call

```
val df = ....
val df2 = df.setNullableStateOfColumn( "id", true )
```

### Edit

#### Alternative solution 1

Use a slight modified version of `setNullableStateOfColumn`

```
def setNullableStateForAllColumns( df: DataFrame, nullable: Boolean) : DataFrame = {
  // get schema
  val schema = df.schema
  // modify [[StructField] with name `cn`
  val newSchema = StructType(schema.map {
    case StructField( c, t, _, m) ⇒ StructField( c, t, nullable = nullable, m)
  })
  // apply new schema
  df.sqlContext.createDataFrame( df.rdd, newSchema )
}
```

#### Alternative solution 2

Explicitely define the schema. (Use reflection to create a solution that is more general)

```
configuredUnitTest("Stackoverflow.") { sparkContext =>

  case class Input(id:Long, var1:Int, var2:Int, var3:Double)

  val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sparkContext)
  import sqlContext.implicits._


  // use this to set the schema explicitly or
  // use refelection on the case class member to construct the schema
  val schema = StructType( Seq (
    StructField( "id", LongType, true),
    StructField( "var1", IntegerType, true),
    StructField( "var2", IntegerType, true),
    StructField( "var3", DoubleType, true)
  ))

  val is: List[Input] = List(
    Input(1110, 0, 1001,-10.00),
    Input(1111, 1, 1001, 10.00),
    Input(1111, 0, 1002, 10.00)
  )

  val rdd: RDD[Input] =  sparkContext.parallelize( is )
  val rowRDD: RDD[Row] = rdd.map( (i: Input) ⇒ Row(i.id, i.var1, i.var2, i.var3))
  val inputDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame( rowRDD, schema ) 

  inputDF.printSchema
  inputDF.show()
}
```

Comment: So there is no way to just do a blanket reset of the columns?  I can always grab the column names into a list and loop through that list if I need to.  BTW, the "pimp my library" thing is awesome!

Comment: Ahhh, now I know what you mean. You can specify a schema  via `StructType` with `createDataFrame`. Will add an edit to my answer.

Comment: All this to enable what is typically a default behavior in just about any SQL engine: that a field can contain nulls?

Comment: My observation is that this creates a logical plan on the source RDD, resulting in extra processing - and it seems to be considered an action since my stage now stops at the `createDataFrame` line, rather than some later processing stage.

Answer (score 42):

Another option, if you need to change dataframe in-place, and recreating is impossible, you can do something like this:

```
.withColumn("col_name", when(col("col_name").isNotNull, col("col_name")).otherwise(lit(null)))
```

Spark will then think that this column may contain `null`, and nullability will be set to `true`.
Also, you can use `udf`, to wrap your values in `Option`.
Works fine even for streaming cases.

Comment: Any idea how to achieve the inverse (set a column as non-nullable) in a structured streaming dataframe?

Comment: Nice! And the PySpark version is `.withColumn("col_name", when(col("col_name").isNotNull(), col("col_name")).otherwise(lit(None)))`

Comment: `otherwise` seems not needed. It's shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68578277#68578278)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: `Works fine even for streaming cases.`
For me this works only when foreachBatch sink is used. For other sinks, it seemingly works but not really - checking df schema shows that nullable changed from false to true, but somehow the column still behaves as if nullable=false. To give a specific example, calling `to_avro` on the changed column (without providing the schema to `to_avro`, which is the only way for spark 2.4) yields avro bytes of the value directly, without the initial int indicating position in the avro union (i.e. behavior for nullable=false instead of behavior for nullable=true).

Answer (score 17):

This is a late answer, but wanted to give an alternative solution for people that come here. You can automatically make a `DataFrame` `Column` nullable from the start by the following modification to your code:

```
case class input(id:Option[Long], var1:Option[Int], var2:Int, var3:Double)
val inputDF = sqlContext
  .createDataFrame(List(input(Some(1110),Some(0),1001,-10.00),
    input(Some(1111),Some(1),1001,10.00),
    input(Some(1111),Some(0),1002,10.00)))
inputDF.printSchema
```

This will yield:

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- var1: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- var2: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- var3: double (nullable = false)

defined class input
inputDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: bigint, var1: int, var2: int, var3: double]
```

Essentially, if you declare a field as an `Option` by using `Some([element])` or `None` as the actual inputs, then that field be nullable. Otherwise, the field will not be nullable. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 10):

#### More compact version of setting all columns nullable parameter

Instead of `case StructField( c, t, _, m) ⇒ StructField( c, t, nullable = nullable, m)` one can use `_.copy(nullable = nullable)`. Then the whole function can be written as:

```
def setNullableStateForAllColumns( df: DataFrame, nullable: Boolean) : DataFrame = {
  df.sqlContext.createDataFrame(df.rdd, StructType(df.schema.map(_.copy(nullable = nullable))))
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks [Martin Senne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1211082/martin-senne).
Just a little addition. In case of inner struct types, you may need to set *nullable* recursively, like this:

```
def setNullableStateForAllColumns(df: DataFrame, nullable: Boolean): DataFrame = {
    def set(st: StructType): StructType = {
      StructType(st.map {
        case StructField(name, dataType, _, metadata) =>
          val newDataType = dataType match {
            case t: StructType => set(t)
            case _ => dataType
          }
          StructField(name, newDataType, nullable = nullable, metadata)
      })
    }

    df.sqlContext.createDataFrame(df.rdd, set(df.schema))
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use java.lang.Integer instead of scala.Int in your case class.

```
case class input(id:Long, var1:java.lang.Integer , var2:java.lang.Integer , var3:java.lang.Double)
```

Comment: sir any specific reason why we need to prefer java Integer rather than spark ?

Answer (score 2):

As I came here searching for a pyspark solution and did not find one, here it is:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
[(1, "a", 4), (3, "B", 5)], ("col1", "col2", "col3"))

df.show()
df.schema

+----+----+----+  
|col1|col2|col3|  
+----+----+----+  
|   1|   a|   4|  
|   3|   B|   5|  
+----+----+----+  

StructType(
    List(
        StructField(col1,LongType,true),
        StructField(col2,StringType,true),
        StructField(col3,LongType,true)
    )
)

schema = StructType()
for field in df.schema.fields:
    schema.add(StructField(field.name, field.dataType, False))
newdf = spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, schema)

newdf.schema
StructType(
    List(
        StructField(col1,LongType,false),
        StructField(col2,StringType,false),
        StructField(col3,LongType,false)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to drop a column and create a new column in spark dataframe, you can create a nullable column like.

1. df.withColumn("Employee_Name", when(lit('') == '', '').otherwise(lit(None)))

***NOTE***: The above code works if you want to create a column of type string and also make it nullable

2. df.withColumn("Employee_Name", when(lit('') == '', 0).otherwise(lit(None)))

***NOTE***: The above code works if you want to create a column of type integer and also make it nullable

Comment: Problem statement is to change schema of existing and not creating new columns

Comment: Sometimes its easy to drop the column and create a new column with the updated schema, I was searching for this answer but nobody posted this. So I thought this will be helpful for someone.