# Spark Dataframe column nullable property change

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to change the nullable property of a particular column in a Spark Dataframe.

If I print schema of the dataframe currently it looks like below.

```
col1: string (nullable = false)
col2: string (nullable = true)
col3: string (nullable = false)
col4: float (nullable = true)
```

I just want `col3` nullable property to be updated.

```
col1: string (nullable = false)
col2: string (nullable = true)
col3: string (nullable = true)
col4: float (nullable = true)
```

I checked online here are some links, but seems like they are doing it for all the columns but not to a specific column, see
[Change nullable property of column in spark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33193958/change-nullable-property-of-column-in-spark-dataframe).
Can any one please help me in this regard?

Comment: I am performing some action on one column by using .withColumn. After that i performed a printSchema then in the schema i observed that nullable is getting updated as nullable = true by default. How can i control that nullable value(true or false).

Comment: In general value of `nullable` attribute is defined by the semantics of the  input (primitives / boxed primitives / Option) or function you apply. So _some action_ is important here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "clear" way to do this. You can use trick like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33193958/change-nullable-property-of-column-in-spark-dataframe)

Relevant code from that answer:

```
def setNullableStateOfColumn( df: DataFrame, cn: String, nullable: Boolean) : DataFrame = {

  // get schema
  val schema = df.schema
  // modify [[StructField] with name `cn`
  val newSchema = StructType(schema.map {
    case StructField( c, t, _, m) if c.equals(cn) => StructField( c, t, nullable = nullable, m)
    case y: StructField => y
  })
  // apply new schema
  df.sqlContext.createDataFrame( df.rdd, newSchema )
}
```

It would copy DataFrame and copy schema, but with specyfying nullable programatically

Version for many columns:

```
def setNullableStateOfColumn(df: DataFrame, nullValues: Map[String, Boolean]) : DataFrame = {

  // get schema
  val schema = df.schema
  // modify [[StructField]s with name `cn`
  val newSchema = StructType(schema.map {
    case StructField( c, t, _, m) if nullValues.contains(c) => StructField( c, t, nullable = nullValues.get(c), m)
    case y: StructField => y
  })
  // apply new schema
  df.sqlContext.createDataFrame( df.rdd, newSchema )
}
```

Usage:
    setNullableStateOfColumn(df1, Map ("col1" -> true, "col2" -> true, "col7" -> false));

Comment: I think this way I cannot change the nullable value of only one particular column from the dataframe.

Comment: Technically, you're not changing, but creating new dataset with new schema. Look at line with `case StructField` - there is `if` column name is equal to column name from argument, then set nullability as given from parameter. If not, column data will be copied

Comment: So if I have 4 columns in a dataframe and i had to modify nullable value for only one column.                                                                                            val df2 = df1.withColumn("col1", udfname(df1, "col1", true))                                                 and then i need to call that method "setNullableStateOfColumn" through udf function which i created ?

Comment: udf will be something like val udfname = udf(setNullableStateOfColumn _)                please let me know. Thanks

Comment: No, just invoke `setNullableStateOfColumn (df1, "col1", false)`, not as UDF but normal function

Comment: @Ramesh it worked? Have you got any additional questions?

Comment: Hi Gaweda, Sorry i had to be away for some time. I am trying to solve this now.

Comment: @Gaweda, Its working for single column. How can i modify the setNullableStateOfColumn function to work on more than one column's nullable property?

Comment: I know that my question was actually for one column, but i also would like to know for more than one column. Can you please reply on the same.

Comment: @ Gaweda, How to invoke this new function which had Map datatype as a argument. I mean if I create a Map with name "colNullableValues".                                             

val colNullableValues = Map("Col1" -> "false, "Col2" -> "true", "col3" -> "true")

setNullableStateOfColumn(df1, colNullableValues)

Comment: It is map string-> boolean, not string->string

Comment: val colNullableValues = Map("Col1" -> false, "Col2" -> true, "col3" -> true)

Comment: And now `setNullableStateOfColumn(df1, colNullableValues)`, just like it was in answer

Comment: @Gaweda,  The code above which we were discussing is for direct columns. But if we have a array field in dataframe and which has 3 columns in it whose schema is like below.       

|-- arraycol: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- col2: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- col3: string (nullable = true)

Comment: `  val colNullableValues = Map("Col1" -> false, "Col2" -> true, "col3" -> true)

  def setNullableStateOfmultiColumn(df: DataFrame, nullValues: Map[String, Boolean]) : DataFrame = {

    // get schema
    val schema = df.schema
    // modify [[StructField]s with name `cn`
    val newSchema = StructType(schema.map {
      case StructField( c, t, _, m) if colNullableValues.contains(c) => StructField( c, t, nullable = nullValues.get(c), m)
      case y: StructField => y
    })
    // apply new schema
    df.sqlContext.createDataFrame( df.rdd, newSchema )
  }`

Comment: @Gaweda I am not able use your code for multi column. I used the above code for defining it. I am getting an issue saying cannot resolve StructField with such signature and also nullValues.get(c) its saying type mismatch, it is expecting Boolean but found Option[Boolean]. Can you please help to resolve.