# Can I change the nullability of a column in my Spark dataframe?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a StructField in a dataframe that is not nullable. Simple example:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *
l = [('Alice', 1)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(l, ['name', 'age'])
df = df.withColumn('foo', F.when(df['name'].isNull(),False).otherwise(True))
df.schema.fields
```

which returns:

> [StructField(name,StringType,true),
>    StructField(age,LongType,true),
>    StructField(foo,BooleanType,false)]

Notice that the field `foo` is not nullable. Problem is that (for reasons I won't go into) I want it to be nullable. I found this post [Change nullable property of column in spark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33193958/change-nullable-property-of-column-in-spark-dataframe) which suggested a way of doing it so I adapted the code therein to this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *
l = [('Alice', 1)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(l, ['name', 'age'])
df = df.withColumn('foo', F.when(df['name'].isNull(),False).otherwise(True))
df.schema.fields
newSchema = [StructField('name',StringType(),True), StructField('age',LongType(),True),StructField('foo',BooleanType(),False)]
df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df.rdd, newSchema)
```

which failed with:

> TypeError: StructField(name,StringType,true) is not JSON serializable

I also see this in the stack trace:

> raise ValueError("Circular reference detected")

So I'm a bit stuck. Can anyone modify this example in a way that enables me to define a dataframe where column `foo` is nullable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems you missed the StructType(newSchema).

```
l = [('Alice', 1)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(l, ['name', 'age'])
df = df.withColumn('foo', F.when(df['name'].isNull(),False).otherwise(True))
df.schema.fields
newSchema = [StructField('name',StringType(),True), StructField('age',LongType(),True),StructField('foo',BooleanType(),False)]
df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df.rdd, StructType(newSchema))
df2.show()
```

Answer (score 11):

I know this question is already answered, but I was looking for a more generic solution when I came up with this:

```
def set_df_columns_nullable(spark, df, column_list, nullable=True):
    for struct_field in df.schema:
        if struct_field.name in column_list:
            struct_field.nullable = nullable
    df_mod = spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, df.schema)
    return df_mod
```

You can then call it like this:

```
set_df_columns_nullable(spark,df,['name','age'])
```

Comment: Great answer. Are there any performance implications in doing this? What exactly happens when you "create a new dataframe" based on the existing RDD?

Comment: Is there any way by which this can be done in scala?

Comment: @malthe and others come here, seems this is super costly, i tested it with a 10X1 df only, and the one without updating the nullable took `184.47592 ms` while with this update nullable in place took `1187.75746 ms`

Answer (score 10):

For the general case, one can change the nullability of a column via the `nullable` property of the `StructField` of that specific column.
Here's an example:

```
df.schema['col_1']
# StructField(col_1,DoubleType,false)

df.schema['col_1'].nullable = True

df.schema['col_1']
# StructField(col_1,DoubleType,true)
```

Comment: this seems to only work if i re-create the dataframe with the schema change. is there no way to do this "in-line"?

Comment: [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46119565/3692004) shows how to change the nullable property in-place.

Answer (score -1):

One can use the SPARK SQL that is ANSI compliant. In this case the [ALTER](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-alter-table.html#alter-or-change-column) statement is necessary.

Please see examples:

to **unset** the nullability:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name DROP NOT NULL;
```

to **set** the nullability:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name SET NOT NULL;
```

Comment: What you've described here change the nullability of a table in a column, the question was asking about a column in a dataframe.

Comment: typo. I meant ... "change the nullability of a column in a table"

Answer (score -6):

```
df1 = df.rdd.toDF()
df1.printSchema()
```

Output:

```
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: long (nullable = true)
 |-- foo: boolean (nullable = true)
```