# How can I change the nullable property of a nested struct field in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I got reference from [Can I change the nullability of a column in my Spark dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46072411/can-i-change-the-nullability-of-a-column-in-my-spark-dataframe) ; but it didn't work for my case.

I have a field Schools and it is of nested Struct Type

```
StructField(schools,ArrayType(StructType(List(StructField(name,StringType,true),StructField(category,StringType,true),StructField(district,StringType,true))),true),true)
```

I want to change the nullability of name and category, how can I do that ?

I have tried `df.schema["schools.name"].nullable = False`, but it didn't work.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue, have you figured out a way? thanks