# Databricks pyspark - specify schema nullability of dataframe returned by spark.sql()

Tags: pyspark, databricks-sql

Is there a way to specify the schema of a pyspark DataFrame returned by a query within `df = spark.sql(...)`? Specifically, I am looking for a way to specify some columns must be `nullable = false`.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51821437) shows you can change the schema by creating a new DataFrame using `spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, df.schema)`, but as a comment mentions, it is very costly.

Comment: How will you use this information? If you want to drop rows with null, you can use "where". If you want to get notified on nulls you can load the dataframe and then check.

Answer (score 1):

df.schema["column name"].nullability = True