# How to modify a dataframe in-place so that its ArrayType column can't be null (nullable = false and containsNull = false)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Take the following example dataframe:

```scala
val df = Seq(Seq("xxx")).toDF("a")
```

Schema:

```
root
 |-- a: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

How can I modify `df` in-place so that the resulting dataframe is not nullable anywhere, i.e. has the following schema:

```
root
 |-- a: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
```

I understand that I can re-create another dataframe enforcing a non-nullable schema, such as following [Change nullable property of column in spark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33193958/1602266)

```scala
spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, StructType(StructField("a", ArrayType(StringType, false), false) :: Nil))
```

But this is not an option under structured streaming, so I want it to be some kind of in-place modification.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change nullable property of column in spark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33193958/change-nullable-property-of-column-in-spark-dataframe)

Comment: So what do you want to happen when you try to convert an array with a null element to a DataFrame?

Comment: @Lamanus If I understand it correctly, answers under that question do not address my situation. As I mentioned in question description, `createDataFrame` is not possible in structured streaming. Are you suggesting re-creating dataframe in a `foreachBatch` sink for each micro-batch dataframe?

Comment: @kfkhalili I can make sure all null elements have already been filtered out from previous stages of dataframe transformation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the way to achieve this is with a `UserDefinedFunction`

```
// Problem setup
val df = Seq(Seq("xxx")).toDF("a")

df.printSchema
root
|-- a: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Onto the solution:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{ArrayType, StringType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{udf, col}

// We define a sub schema with the appropriate data type and null condition
val subSchema = ArrayType(StringType, containsNull = false)

// We create a UDF that applies this sub schema
// while specifying the output of the UDF to be non-nullable
val applyNonNullableSchemaUdf =  udf((x:Seq[String]) => x, subSchema).asNonNullable

// We apply the UDF
val newSchemaDF = df.withColumn("a", applyNonNullableSchemaUdf(col("a")))
```

And there you have it.

```
// Check new schema
newSchemaDF.printSchema
root
|-- a: array (nullable = false)
|    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)

// Check that it actually works
newSchemaDF.show
+-----+
|    a|
+-----+
|[xxx]|
+-----+
```