# Adding a nullable column in Spark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, nullable

In Spark, literal columns, when added, are not nullable:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions as F
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,)], ['c1'])

df = df.withColumn('c2', F.lit('a'))

df.printSchema()
#  root
#   |-- c1: long (nullable = true)
#   |-- c2: string (nullable = false)
```

How to create a nullable column?

Comment: the real question is "why would you need to have a lit null column ...

Comment: In my case, I needed to create the schema identic to another dataframe, but with different data in it. This includes nullability.

Comment: why don't you create a schema directly then ? starting from df.schema.

Comment: I thnik you should create another question with your original usecase. Currently, you are trying to find help for a solution you imagined but probably not the proper one. It is called [XY_problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: Sorry, but If you cannot imagine a use case it does not mean it does not exist. I had this issue and found an answer [here](https://dev.to/kevinwallimann/how-to-make-a-column-non-nullable-in-spark-structured-streaming-4b62). Then I made it even better so I decided to post it here. Later I read more and found [this highly-upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33193958#46119565) to a different problem. I think those cases prove that use case exists, whatever original issue people may have. I just wanted to help someone else to find the answer easier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The shortest method I've found - using `when` (the `otherwise` clause seems not needed):

```py
df = df.withColumn('c2', F.when(F.lit(True), F.lit('a')))
```

If in Scala: `.withColumn("c2", when(lit(true), lit("a")))`

---

Full test result:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions as F
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,)], ['c1'])
df = df.withColumn('c2', F.when(F.lit(True), F.lit('a')))

df.show()
#  +---+---+
#  | c1| c2|
#  +---+---+
#  |  1|  a|
#  +---+---+

df.printSchema()
#  root
#   |-- c1: long (nullable = true)
#   |-- c2: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Uau, pretty good man, you saved me! I wouldn't like to build so much code to do something tiny. Thank you!