# pyspark.sql.functions.lit() not nullable conversion

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

As I create a new column with `F.lit(1)`, while calling `printSchema()` I get

```
column_name: integer (nullable = false)
```

as lit function docs is quite scarce, do you think there is any simple mapping that can be done to turn it into `nullable = true`?

Comment: As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68578277/adding-a-nullable-column-in-spark-dataframe), instead of `F.lit(1)`, you can use `F.when(F.lit(True), F.lit(1))`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, in this scenario (only some specific column mapping, nothing in bulk) it seems like

`df.schema['column_name'].nullable = True`

does the trick. Nevertheless `df.printSchema()` isn't updated, although `df.schema` is.

Comment: Hey, Did you figure out why printSchema and schema are giving different result?