# Spark withColumn changes column nullable property in schema

Tags: apache-spark

I'm using `withColumn` in order to override a certain column (applying the same value to the entire data frame), my problem is that withColumn changes the nullable property of the column:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StringType, StructField, StructType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit

val schema = StructType(Array(
                 StructField("id", StringType, true),
                 StructField("name", StringType, true)
             ))
val data = Seq(Row(1, "pepsi"), Row(2, "coca cola"))
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
val df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
df.withColumn("name", lit("*******"))
df.printSchema
```

result:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = false)
```

The best idea I have is change the schema after the manipulation, was wondering if someone has a better idea.

Thanks!

Comment: Check the 2nd answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33193958/change-nullable-property-of-column-in-spark-dataframe

Comment: Mohana is right, the Literal column's nullable is defined as : `override def nullable: Boolean = value == null (Literal's source code)`, so we cant change it.   that answer wrap it by `when`.